# Rotas Laravel / Angular $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-rotas, angular-routes

Tenho algo desse tipo no app.js da minha aplicação:

```
app.config( function( $routeProvider ) {
    $routeProvider.when('evento/:id/:caminho', {
        templateUrl: 'views/evento.html',
        controller: 'PrincipalEventoController'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('evento/:id/:caminho/sobre', {
        templateUrl: 'views/sobre.html',
        controller: 'SobreEventoController'
    });
```

Na rota do Laravel está `localhost:8000/evento/1/nome-do-evento`.
Tenho uma div com `ng-view` na página.

O problema é que a div com `ng-view` não está carregando o conteúdo que desejo. Nem a view, nem o controller definidos no app.js.
Sempre dá a mensagem "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found".
Acredito que a solução é simples, mas não estou conseguindo e resolvi pedir a ajuda dos mestres.

Abraço a todos.

Answer (score 1):

David,

A sua concepção que está errada. A rotas criadas no Laravel (Framework PHP) não tem nada a ver com as rotas criadas com Angularjs (Framework Javascript), já comunicação estabelecida entre Angular e Laravel é o que acontece.

No *Laravel* com *Angular*, é criado as **Views Html** dentro da pasta `public/html` (ou pode ser qualquer nome de pasta dentro da pasta `public`), ou seja, não sendo necessário passar pelo `controller` do Laravel já visto que são trechos de html com `tags` do *Angular*

Se código Javascript (Angular) seria assim:

```
app.config( function( $routeProvider ) 
{

    $routeProvider.when('evento/:id/:caminho', 
    {
        templateUrl: '/html/evento.html',
        controller: 'PrincipalEventoController'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('evento/:id/:caminho/sobre', 
    {
        templateUrl: '/html/sobre.html',
        controller: 'SobreEventoController'
    });

});
```

E sua organização de pastas seria assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem demonstra dentro da **pasta** `public` a **pasta** `html` com o arquivo Html `clientes.html`, sendo esse um exemplo demostrando o local correto do `html` da sua ***app Angular***

O seu link para chamar os itens criados no laravel seria

```
<a href="#/evento/1/caminho" aria-controls="evento" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Eventos 1 Caminho</a>
```

Siga esse exemplo trocando a `templateUrl` igual eu lhe disse sobre a pasta e execute normalmente criando um link como demostrado no exemplo...